# Idiom request about conversation

Tags: idiom-requests

Is there any idiom or expression for this:
To make a conversation and talk about many different and irrelevant subjects, keep changing the topics frequently and so.
Thanks

Comment: There are various single words, such as _babble_ and _prattle_.

Answer (score 1):

Such a conversation can be called "[small talk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/small%20talk)."  People can "make small talk" or, less common, "engage in small talk."  The canonical small-talk topic is the weather, but the performance of sports teams, health and activities of family, and a wide variety of other generally inconsequential topics might come up in such a conversation.

"Small talk" is distinguished from @surlawda's family of suggestions in that his suggest actively avoiding one or more specific consequential topics, whereas small talk is more about generally keeping the topics light, so as to enjoy conversing.  Small talk is for passing time without risking conflict or deep engagement.

Answer (score 0):

[***go/fly off on tangents***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=off+on+a+tangent%2Coff+on+tangents&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coff%20on%20a%20tangent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coff%20on%20tangents%3B%2Cc0)

> go off on a tangent
>
> : to suddenly start talking about a different subject *We were talking about property prices and you went off on a tangent.*
>
> [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+off+on+a+tangent)

***flit from one topic to another***; also [***jump from one subject to another***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-spanish/to-jump-from-one-subject-to-another)

> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22flit+from+one+topic+to+another%22&prmd=inv&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb4Ify3ObLAhVL5xoKHYztANUQ_AUIDCgG&biw=399&bih=262&dpr=2)
>
> **flit**
>
> : to fly or move swiftly, lightly, or irregularly from one place or thing to another.
>
> [Random-House Kennerman Webster's Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flit)

***be all over the place***

> *"All over the place” is a saying that usually means someone or something is scattered, disorganized, or confusing [...]*
>
> *Sometimes the saying is used figuratively, making it an idiomatic expression. A person can say, “She was ill prepared for the speech. Her thoughts were all over the place.” Obviously, thoughts are not objects to be touched or thrown about, but in this case the woman’s thoughts were scattered or disorganized. She might have begun the speech by talking about elephants and then accidentally ended up talking about body lotions.*
>
> [WiseGeek](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-does-it-mean-to-be-all-over-the-place.htm)

***ride (madly) off in all directions***

> *Fig.* To behave in a totally confused manner; to try to do everything at once.
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ride+off+in+all+directions)

Answer (score 0):

- [***chit chat***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chitchat)

  > friendly conversation about things that are not very important

  Some of the online dictionaries list it as a single word (***chitchat***) or possibly a hyphenated word (***chit-chat***).
- [***idle chat***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=idle+chat)

  > Meaningless talking ..., filling the silence or occupying time while waiting.

  or [***idle talk***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/idle+talk)

  > idle or foolish and irrelevant talk

  or ***idle conversation***.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like **shooting the breeze**:

> *Fig*. to chat casually and without purpose. *We spent the entire afternoon just shooting the breeze. It was good to shoot the breeze with you, Mary.* - [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+the+breeze)